# Convolution of infinite sums

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

[We have](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fubini%27s_theorem)

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(n) \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}g(m) = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}g(m) f(n)
$$

and

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y) dy  = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(y) dy dx
$$

but do we have below?

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(t, n) \star \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}g(t, m) = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(t, n) \star g(t, m)
$$

Can we argue

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega, n) \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} G(\omega, m) = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} F(\omega, n) G(\omega, m)
$$

per distributive property, and let $f_0(t) = f(t, 0)$,

$$
(f_0(t) + f_1(t)) \star (g_0(t) + g_1(t)) = f_0(t) \star g_0(t) + f_0(t) \star g_1(t) + ...
$$

though funky stuff happens with infinite series, and we also need to satisfy the Fubini theorem's absolute convergence criterion, which, for one, for sums is written only for when $f(n)$ is a single discrete point rather than an entire continuous function.

---

- $\star$ = convolution; $(f \star g)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g(\tau - t) dt$
- $f(t, n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \cos(t)$ (example)
- $t, \omega \in \mathbb{R}, -\infty < t, \omega < \infty$

Comment: I assume you mean $*$ for convolution, not  $\star$ for correlation?

Comment: It would help if you explain your notation and symbols a bit. What exactly $f(t,n)$ ? A  bivariate function that is both dependent on a continuous variable $t$ and a discrete variable $n$ ?

Comment: You could try: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871203/how-to-multiply-two-infinite-series-correctly .  But to be clear.  If t is a _parameter_ then your right, and it's called a product.  
but, if its an indexing variable for power series than you have a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product . Which is normally called a series convolution.  Normally, to say you need "convolution" you need a linkage between the first sum and the second.  There are a lot of different "convolutions" and you must be specific about the (presumed) linkage between the first and second term.

Comment: @rrogers What's "linkage"? I clarified. And what do you mean "it's called a product"? The expression in question is a convolution of infinite sums, not a product - and the question _is_ whether we can rewrite it as a product via convolution theorem.

Comment: In ordinary usage, convolution means that a summation/integral is summed over a common variable; like your explanation.  In your examples, $\omega$ , t are never summed over.  Presumably you meant too, but it's not in the correct form.  In addition, the summation variable should be missing after "convolution".  Now, there are a _lot_ of "convolutions" in use.  Look at the last four entries in the Properties' table of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform.  The summation variable "y" disappears; but is the key to the "convolution" mathematical form; as is your  "*" explanation.

Comment: @rrogers Not summing over $\omega, t$ is intentional, since otherwise there'd be nothing to convolve: the sums reduce to constants. "The summation variable should be missing after convolution" - no, the two are independent. The idea is, we're convolving some final functions, $(f_\text{fin} \star g_\text{fin})(\tau)$, but we only have their closed form expressions in an infinite sum.

Comment: Coming from an EE background, with a lot of mathematics, I think this paper  probably would be "common ground".  It resembles both of our statements (more or less).  The top of page 3  gives an explicit definition; phrased in terms I would have to get used to.  
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267046448_Convolution_Separation_and_Concurrency

Comment: Also a "formal" discussion of quantale : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04603.pdf  "Convolutions f ∗ g have been introduced in Sch¨utzenberger and Eilenberg’s approach to formal language theory [BR84]. In this case, x, y and z are words from some free monoid X∗ and R x y z corresponds to x = y · z. Similar forms of convolution have been considered widely in mathematics. Many well-known constructions from computer science can be represented this way [DHS16]."

Comment: @rrogers I'm unsure what you're trying to convey, but I think the definition in question is unambiguous? Do your references touch upon convolutions of infinite sums?

Comment: " I think the definition in question is unambiguous?" I don't.  I think we are attributing two different meanings to "convolution", so I am resorting to an axiomatic approach.  Those references use a "formal" approach that should (might?) provide a precise meaning for the word.  The formal "proof" languages are usable to pin down the meaning of human words; not perfect, though (as of a couple of years ago).  If you want, I shall try to find a more mathematical characterization.  Let me search through the MAA archives :)

Comment: 1) When "Formal" series are considered; convergence of the generating function is irrelevant.  In this context, the "result" is the coefficients.  2) Here is a paper that talks about convergence in a mathematical way that would seem to be "common ground".  Notice the upper limit on the summation; that is the "linkage" that I refer to: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04603.pdf  --  And "y" and "z" take all possible values, subject to the constraint "x=y*z, and are thus erased from the output.  Now the generalization or convolution would be merely changing x=y*z to x=G(y,z).

Comment: but possibly you are tacitly assuming the "convolution" referred to on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution  -- which is a very narrow view of the word.  I have two or three books that reasonably use the word in a more general manner; which I can (try) to list :)

Comment: @rrogers If you're commenting on definitions, in signal processing we're unanimous on "convolution", though we certainly don't claim it to be the only one - just one for this question. Thanks for the effort, but it appears to be going off-topic.